# Electron app can't find resources when openAtLogin is set

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have app that set `app.setLoginItemSettings({openAtLogin: true})` but when i reload my machine i have error of files dont found, but when i launch app from shortcut all files is founded and dont trow error.

In `background.js` i have:

```js
const image = nativeImage.createFromPath('resources/img/logo.png');

/**
 * ->openAtLogin: true
 * image is empty
 *
 * ->run from shortcut
 * image set
 */
```

In `vue.config.js` i have:

```js
(...)
        electronBuilder: {
            builderOptions: {
                (...)
                // to copy resources from project to package resources folder
                extraResources: [
                    {
                        from: "resources",
                        to: ""
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The proplem that on autolaunch root folder is `C:\Windows\system32` and not app folder.
Becuase of that is necessary to get `resources_path`.

Example:

```js
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const resources_path = isDevelopment? path.resolve('./'): path.dirname(process.execPath);
const image = nativeImage.createFromPath(`${resources_path}/resources/img/logo.png`);
```